# Configure Matlab to Run Inside Shell

Tags: matlab, shell, command

Is it possible to configure MATLAB to **run inside the shell**?, i.e. for a command line user from a ssh connection without additional windows, only direct commands through the shell, like this:

```
C:\> matlab
To get started, type doc.
For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.
>> x=1
x = 
     1
>> exit;
C:\>
```

I know by executing the following command from the shell you open MATLAB in a **new** window, but I am asking about executing in the same shell, as in the above example:

```
C:\> matlab -nodesktop -nosplash
```

Also, the command below **shows all messages in the shell**, but it is not interactive:

```
C:\> matlab -batch myfunc
hello, world
C:\>
```